# Using line integrals and green's theorem to find integral of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, partial-derivative, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Let $f : \mathbb C → \mathbb C$ be a function of class $C^1$
(not necessarily holomorphic); write $f = u + iv$.

Let $Ω ⊂ C$ be a domain with boundary $bΩ = C$, where $C$ is a simple, closed, piecewise differentiable curve.

Define the planar vector fields $F_1 = ui − vj$,

$F_2 = vi + uj$.

(a) Show that $\int_C{f(z)dz} = \int_C{F1 · dr} +i \int_C{F2 · dr} $.

(b) Use Green’s theorem to show that $\int_C{f(z)dz} = 2i \int \int_Ω {\frac{∂f} {∂\bar{z}}} dxdy$.

(c) What can we conclude if $f$ is $C^1$ and complex differentiable?

My attempts:

a) I know that $\int_C {F1 · dr}$ = $\int_C ∇f_1. dr$, so if I want to find the potential function $f_1$, I say that $f_{1x} = u(x, y) $ and so $f_1 = \int{u(x, y)}dx = h(x, y) + g(y) $ where $h(x, y)$ is a function in $x$ and $y$ and $g(y)$ is a function in $y$. So $f_{1y} = h_y(x, y) + g'(y) $

And I have $f_{1y} = - v(x, y) $, thus $-v(x, y) = h_y(x, y) +g'(y) $. Hence $g'(y) = -v(x, y) - h_y(x, y) $, so $g(y) = - \int{v(x, y)}dy - \int{h_y(x, y)}dy $

Then $f_1 = - \int{v(x, y)} dy$

I do the same procedure as before to find $f_2 = \int{u(x, y)} dy$

How do I continue from there to prove the equality?

b) I know Green's theorem is $\int_C {Ldx + Mdy} = \int \int_D (\frac{\partial M} {\partial x} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial y}) dxdy$.

How do I proceed from here?

c) I don't really know what to do.

Any help please in the 3 parts? Thank you

Comment: (a) is completely the wrong approach to this problem. There is no need to find such an $f_1$ or $f_2$. This is just a straight-forward comparison of the *definitions* of complex integration vs vector integration. (2) by actually *applying* that equation and part (a). You need to try a little harder than just stating the theorem. (c) If $f$ is complex differentiable, then what do you know about $\dfrac {\partial f}{\partial \overline z}$? (note the complex conjugation of z.)

Comment: Could you please tell me how it is done for parts a) and b)? I'm lost

Comment: What is the definition of $\int_C f(z)\,dz$? What is the definition of $\int_C \vec F(\vec r)\cdot d{\vec r}$? Go look them up and write them out in full.

Comment: Note that by the definitions I do not mean some "epsilon-delta" affair. I am just referring to defining those two variants of integration in terms of integration along the real line, based on the curve $C(t) = (x(t), y(t)) \equiv x(t) + iy(t)$.

Comment: $\int_C {f(z)} dz = \int_C {u(z)} dz + i\int_C {v(z)} dz$ and $\int_C {F}. dr = \int_a^b {\frac{\partial f} {\partial x}. \frac{\partial x} {\partial t}} + \frac{\partial f} {\partial y}. \frac{\partial y} {\partial t} $. How does this imply the equality for part a)?

Comment: Neither of those are correct. $dz$ is not a real differential, and $\vec F = u(x,y)\hat i + v(x,y)\hat j$ for some functions $u, v$. It is not necessarily the gradient of some function $f$. Keep looking. And FYI - the reason I am not just giving you the answer is that I am trying to coax you out of the rut you've fallen in, not help you to dig it deeper.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I've tried to many times since I asked the question but I couldn't solve it. Please help could you show me how it is solved, so that I understand?

Comment: How did you expect you would be able to solve it when it is apparent that you don't even know what these integrals mean? You haven't been able to reproduce the definitions of these integrals. You need to find those definitions and *study* them until you understand them. Until then, there is no point in showing you a solution because you will not understand the solution either. Quote for me the correct definitions, and then we can move forward.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Writing $f(z) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y)$ and $dz = dx + idy$, we have
$\int_C{f(z)}dz = \int_C{u} dx − v dy + i\int_C{u} dy + v dx$
= $\int_a^b({u(x(t), y(t))}\frac{dx(t)}{dt} − v(x(t), y(t))\frac{dy(t)}{dt}) dt
+ i\int_a^b({u(x(t), y(t))} \frac{dy(t)}{dt} + v(x(t), y(t))\frac{dx(t)}{dt}) dt.$ that's concerning part a) is it correct?

Comment: That is correct. Now what about $\int_C \mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf r$? $\mathbf F$ is a map $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$, so $\mathbf F(x,y) = (u(x,y), v(x,y))$ for some real valued functions $u, v$. We *do not* know if it is the gradient of some function $f$, nor do we need such an expression for this. $\mathbf r = (x,y)$ is just the position vector.

Comment: Okay I got part a), I managed to solve it. Could you please help me in part b)?

Comment: And concerning part c) if $f$ is complex differentiable then it is differentiable in the real sense as a function $f: \mathbb R^2 -> \mathbb R^2$, and the differenrial of $f$ is $f'(z) $ and $\frac{\partial f} {\partial {\bar{z}}}$ = $1/2(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+ i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}) $, but what does this tell me?

Comment: Sorry, but I have to get back to work. I'll say more tonight.

Comment: Complex differentiation is stronger than real differentiation. What else must $f$ satisfy to be complex differentiable? Also, your expression for $\dfrac {\partial f}{\partial {\overline z}}$ is not correct.

Comment: The Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: Yes, and I apologize for saying your expression for $\dfrac {\partial f}{\partial {\overline z}}$ was incorrect. The problem was my faulty memory of a formula I haven't looked at in many years. The only thing it needs is for you to take the next step of writing $f = u+iv$.

Comment: for part (b), now that you know that $\int_C f(z)\,dz = \int_C \mathbf F_1 \cdot d\mathbf r + i\int_C \mathbf F_2 \cdot d\mathbf r$, apply Green's theorem to each of the two integrals, and then combine the results.